# Unable to access an error message - Callback validation in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have simple code thats not working. I made validation for checkbox and I get error:

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name accept_terms_checkbox.(accept_terms)

This is my code:

Controller:

```
public function formularz2()
{



    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['szkolenia'] = $this->Szkolenie_m->pobierz();


    //VALIDATION!!
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('imie', 'Imię', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Błąd: wypełnij powyższe pole');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('accept_terms_checkbox', 'checkbox', 'callback_accept_terms');

    //CALLBACK FUNCTION!!
    function accept_terms()
    {
  if ($this->input->post('accept_terms_checkbox'))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $error = 'Please read and accept our terms and conditions.';
        $this->form_validation->set_message('accept_terms', $error);
        return FALSE;
    }
    }


    //Po przesłaniu danych

    if (!empty($_POST))
    {
    $konsultant = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $dane = array(
        'email1' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'imie' => $this->input->post('imie'),
        'nazwisko' => $this->input->post('nazwisko'),
        'nazwa_firmy' => $this->input->post('firma'),
        'konsultant_id' => $konsultant,
    );

    //Trzeba jeszcze tutaj ogarnąć wrzucanie pivotów zaznaczonych checkboxów    
    $boxes = $_POST['formChecks'];
    $N = count($boxes);
    $ostatni_id = $this->Osoby_m->ostatni_id();


    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
            $this->Osoby_m->nowy_wpis_formularz($boxes[$i]);    
    }       

    //Pobrać id dodanej osoby = policzyć ile osób w bazie +1
    $this->Osoby_m->nowa_osoba($dane);  

    }   


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('formularz', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('wyslano_formularz');
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>">
  <p class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imie" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imię:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imie" name="imie" placeholder="Imię" value="<?php echo set_value('imie'); ?>">
      <p class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('imie'); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nazwisko" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nazwisko:        </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nazwisko" name="nazwisko" placeholder="Nazwisko" value="<?php echo set_value('nazwisko'); ?>">
      <p class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('nazwisko'); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firma" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firma:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firma" name="firma" placeholder="Firma" value="<?php echo set_value('firma'); ?>">
      <p class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('firma'); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 30px; margin-top: 30px;">    <h3>Wybierz interesujące Cię szkolenia</h3></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Szkolenia:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">

      <?php foreach ($szkolenia as $szkolenie): ?>
      <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input id="szkolenie<?php echo $szkolenie->id; ?>" type="checkbox" name="formChecks[]" value="<?php echo $szkolenie->id; ?>">     <?php echo $szkolenie->nazwa_szkolenia; ?></label>         
            <br>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
  </div>

//CALLBACK CHECKBOX
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 50px;">
 <input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms_checkbox" value="1"/> Zgadzam się na otrzymywanie maili od firmy Gamma<br>
  <p><?php echo form_error('accept_terms_checkbox') ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" style="margin-top: 50px;">Odbierz Voucher</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: why is the second parameter for `set_rules` empty?

Comment: @Kisaragi It's empty because I display my own $error, and don't need field name. Changed it for try, but still not working.

Comment: you do have a callback method defined correct?

Comment: @Kisaragi What do you mean? I think so, I just uploaded whole controller + View. It looks good for me and still not working.

Comment: are you sure about error?? its displaying the correct message...

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_message('accept_terms', $error);   please change "accept_terms" inside set_message to "accept_terms_checkbox"

Comment: @Learner Still not working, code supposted to be fine, I rewrite it from tutorial: [link](http://fellowtuts.com/codeigniter/form-validation-rule-to-validate-checkbox-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: `$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Błąd: wypełnij powyższe pole');` is checking field named `required`. You don't have such a field name in form.

Comment: @Tpojka This is message for required inputs. I have some of these.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misread `set_rules`.

Comment: Try changing all "accept_terms_checkbox" to "accept_terms", also in the view

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your own callback method with codeigniter's validation class, you must declare the method. IN your case ( add this to your controller or a helper etc...):

```
public function accept_terms($user_input){
       if($user_input != ""){
            return True;
       }else{
           $this->form_validation->set_message('accept_terms_checkbo', 'The %s field can not be empty"');
            return False;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working, I suppose to use it instead of my accept_terms? I Change it and still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by simple validation without callback function. I figure out that I don't need callback function for Terms of Services checkbox.

```
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('accept_terms_checkbox', 'Checkbox', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'You need to accept Terms of Services');
```